# Can't generate signature for Lazada's API in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, encryption, e-commerce, signature, sha256

I am trying to consume Lazada API through HTTP requests in NodeJS and it requires a [signature](https://open.lazada.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=a2o9m.11193535.0.0.4a4a38e4oEkDXP#?nodeId=10451&docId=108069) as one of the parameters. 
To generate that, I'm using the [js-256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256) package but for some reason I'm getting an `IncompleSignature` error.

The exact error message:

```
{ type: 'ISV',
  code: 'IncompleteSignature',
  message: 'The request signature does not conform to lazada standards',
  request_id: '0be6e79215428302067761224' }
```

My code:

```
var sha256 = require('js-sha256');


module.exports = function(app, Request){

    app.get('/', function(req,res){

        var access_token = "myToken";
        var app_key = "myAppKey";
        var order_id = "36835322434";
        var sign_method = "sha256";
        var timestamp = new Date().timestamp;

        var concatenatedString = "/order/items/getaccess_token"+access_token
        +"app_key"+app_key
        +"order_id"+order_id
        +"sign_method"+sign_method
        +"timestamp"+new Date().getTime();


        var hash = sha256.hmac.create("myAppSecret");
        hash.update(concatenatedString);

        var httpRequestLink = "http://api.lazada.co.th/rest/order/items/get?access_token="+access_token
        +"&app_key="+app_key
        +"&order_id="+order_id
        +"&sign_method="+sign_method
        +"&timestamp="+new Date().getTime()
        +"&sign="+hash.hex();

        Request.get(httpRequestLink, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            console.log(JSON.parse(body));
        }); 

    });

}
```

Would really appreciate if someone can help me out here. Thanks

Comment: Could you try changing the url from `http` to `https`?

Answer (score 1):

My code work perfectly with follow generate sign by this package.

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const config = require('config')
const LAZADA_SECRET_KEY = config.get("LAZADA_SECRET_KEY")


exports.encryptMessage = (path) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const encryptMessage = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(path, LAZADA_SECRET_KEY).toString(
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex,
    );

    let sign = encryptMessage.toUpperCase();

    return resolve(sign);
});
```

Comment: For others. From [this page](https://open.lazada.com/doc/doc.htm?spm=a2o9m.11193535.0.0.5e9038e4KXua74#?nodeId=10451&docId=108069) in the step 5. You can convert this line `hex(sha256(/order/getaccess_tokentestapp_key123456order_id1234sign_methodsha256timestamp1517820392000))` to `CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('/order/getaccess_tokentestapp_key123456order_id1234sign_methodsha256timestamp1517820392000', 'helloworld').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex).toUpperCase()`. You will get `4190D32361CFB9581350222F345CB77F3B19F0E31D162316848A2C1FFD5FAB4A` that is the same result like in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to add npm package `lazada-open-platform-sdk` url https://www.npmjs.com/package/lazada-open-platform-sdk.

You can easily call lazada api's by its functions and mostly all are integrated by them.For finanace and seller apis which are not integrated by package for that you can use `access_token` generated by `generateAccessToken` and call apis.